# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Join'

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pyspark, etl, aws-glue

Im new with AWS Glue. Im trying to left join 2 df then moving them to the S3 bucket. But I have a problem with left join syntax. Can you help me to resovle this?. Thanks all!

```
# Script generated for node Join
DropNullFields = DropNullFields.toDF()
user = user.toDF()
user = user.select("*", lower(col('OPRID'))).show()
left_join =DynamicFrame.fromDF( 
    DropNullFields.Join(
        user, 
        DropNullFields["erp"] == user["fin_erp_id"],
        "left"
        ),
    glueContext,
    "left_join",
)
```

Comment: lowercase `join`

Comment: Yeah lower case `join` please

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.join.html#pyspark-sql-dataframe-join

Answer (score 0):

Writing this here as it happened to me as well.

Case 1:
You should use **lowercase** **j**oin instead of **J**oin.

Case 2:
In my case, I was copy-pasting code from one python environment to another, same pandas version (1.3.5). It still was the case that .**J**oin existed in the first environment but not the second... The second had .**j**oin, but not as reach in capabilities (could not join **on** non-index) I suspect something in the environment was corupt, had to reinstall my conda environment...